# How to get text on selected checkbox from listview in android

Tags: android, listview, checkbox

I am working on android  example, when i click on checkbox then it gets the  textviews value of first item(Position) in listview every time. so but i want to get value of selected (position) checkbox textview value. how to solve it please help .i am a fresher.Thanks in advances.

Some Code In BaseAdapter class

```
 public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
{
    ViewItem viewItem = null;
    if(convertView == null)
    {
        viewItem = new ViewItem();
        LayoutInflater layoutInfiater = (LayoutInflater)this.context.getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        //LayoutInflater layoutInfiater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        convertView = layoutInfiater.inflate(R.layout.list_adapter_view, null);

        viewItem.txtTitle = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.inactivelistview);
       // viewItem.txtDescription = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.adapter_text_description);
        convertView.setTag(viewItem);
    }
    else
    {
        viewItem = (ViewItem) convertView.getTag();
    }

    viewItem.txtTitle.setText(valueList.get(position).username);
   // viewItem.txtDescription.setText(valueList.get(position).cources_description);

    return convertView;
}
```

Some Code in activity

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_get_in_active_list);

    listCollege = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listCollege);
    proCollageList = (ProgressBar)findViewById(R.id.proCollageList);

    checkbox = (CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.checkbox_me);

    button  =(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
    new GetHttpResponse(this).execute();
}


public void onCheckboxClicked(View view) {

    boolean checked = ((CheckBox) view).isChecked();

    switch(view.getId()) {
        case R.id.checkbox_me:
            if (checked) {

                username = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.inactivelistview);

                Username =username.getText().toString();
                System.out.println("print username_=== "+Username);
                AlertDialog.Builder alertbox = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

                alertbox.setMessage("Do you want activate "+Username+"?");

                alertbox.setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                      public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), Username+" acivated", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }

                });

                alertbox.setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                    public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "'No' button clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });
               alertbox.show();
            } else
                break;
    }
```

I am getting textviews value of first item(Position) in listview every time.
Please help me how to solve.help me update my code
Thank you so much.......

Comment: Checkbox is in your Activity or in Listview?

Comment: checkbox is in listview

Answer (score 0):

Note that checkbox return array as user can tick multiple elements.

```
ArrayList<String> selectedStrings = new ArrayList<String>();
```

The [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19028621/5761361) describe it in details.

Comment: hi, i could not understand please can u edit my question

Answer (score 0):

use gettag on onCheckboxClicked method so that you can identify which row number checkbox is click . then you can get the textview of that row use row number

Answer (score 0):

If your `CheckBox` is in `ListView` then no need to create ClickListener in `Activity`. Follow below steps to get selected text from `ListView`.

First create a model/pojo class, this will help you to store reference of selected `CheckBox` and also values which is going to show in `ListView`.

```
public class MyModel {

  private boolean isSelected;

  private String name;

   public MyModel(boolean isSelected, String name) {
      this.isSelected = isSelected;
      this.name = name;
    }

   public boolean isSelected() {
     return isSelected;
   }

   public void setSelected(boolean selected) {
    this.isSelected = selected;
   }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

}
```

Create a interface which will work as a callback.

```
public interface ItemSelectListener {
   void getSelectedItemText(String text);
}
```

Refactor your BaseAdapter as now it will accept list of our Model class and also callback listener.

```
public MyAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private final List<MyModel> mDataItems;

    private final ItemSelectListener mItemListener;

    public MyAdapter(List<MyModel> dataItems, ItemSelectListener itemListener)
    mDataItems = dataItems;
    mItemListener = itemListener;
   }

   public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
   {
        ViewItem viewItem = null;
        if(convertView == null) {
            viewItem = new ViewItem();
            LayoutInflater layoutInfiater = (LayoutInflater)this.context.getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
           //LayoutInflater layoutInfiater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
           convertView = layoutInfiater.inflate(R.layout.list_adapter_view, null);

           viewItem.txtTitle = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.inactivelistview);

       // Add checkbox in your view item and confirm id of checkbox
       viewItem.checkBox = (CheckBox)convertView.findViewById(R.id. checkbox_me);
       }
       else {
           viewItem = (ViewItem) convertView.getTag();
       }
       final MyModel data = mDataItems.get(position);
       viewItem.txtTitle.setText(data.getName());
       viewItem.checkBox.setChecked(data.isSelected());
       viewItem.checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton button, boolean checked) 
        {
            data.setSelected(checked);
            if(checked) {
             // Make sure you override this in your Activity
             mItemListener.getSelectedItemText(data.getName());
            }
        }
    });

   return convertView;
   }

}
```

Create datasource for `ListView` in your `Activity`.

```
BaseAdapter adapter = new BaseAdapter(dataItems, itemListener);
```