# Checkbox validation, get only checked boxes

Tags: java, android

I have **lots** of checkboxes in my application and i find it inconvenient to check each item if it is selected or not. So i was wondering if there is a way to get only selected and ignore a bunch of unused checkbox.

Right now, my idea is to do something like this

```
 if (cb1.isChecked()) //do something
 if (cb2.isChecked()) //do something

 ...

 if (cb32.isChecked()) //do something
```

But i find it too much to check every checkbox. Is there a way to get only the selected ones?

***Example***

A **CheckBoxGroup** wherein you can just do something like `checkBoxGroup.getCheckedItems()`

I have checked several libraries but it doesnt work this way.
Any help will be appreciated, thanks in advance! Cheers!

Comment: see `CompoundButton#setOnCheckedChangeListener()` method

Comment: One way is like you can get list of children from your container & check it thats checked or not.

Comment: AS @pskink said, see setOnCheckedChangeListener() : - https://stackoverflow.com/a/19028621/10041106 - https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CompoundButton#setOnCheckedChangeListener(android.widget.CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener) - https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android get text of all checked checkboxes in listView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19027843/android-get-text-of-all-checked-checkboxes-in-listview)

Comment: There is no `CheckBoxGroup`. A `RadioGroup` yes but not `CheckBoxGroup`.

Comment: @pskink Thank you sir, but is there another way possible without listening to every checkbox? I have this button that when i trigger i will get the checked ones, totally ignoring the unchecked. Is it possible or do i really need to use either of the two:  **1. Manually flag the checked ones by using listener** or **2. Loop through each item on button click**. And if i really need to, which one is better?

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/a/19028621/2252830 - here `ArrayList<String> selectedStrings` contains a list of "checked" `CheckBox`es

Comment: @pskink i see, so that means i still have to listen to each checkbox. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can follow the below steps:

1) First get the reference of the parent of all checkboxes. (It might be instance of any type of layout; like find linearlayout. Say,

```
LineartLayout parent  = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.linearlayout);
```

2) Then create an Arraylist of String values; say

```
ArrayList<String> checkedList  = new ArrayList();
```

3) Then run a for loop like

```
for(int i=0; i<parent.getChildCount(); i++){
    if(parent.getChildAt(i) instanceof CheckBox){
        CheckBox checkBox = (CheckBox)parent.getChildAt(i);
        if(checkBox.isChecked()){
            checkedList.add(checkBox.getText());
         } 
     }
}
```

4) And at the end of for loop, you will get the list of checked values.

Answer (score 2):

Try setting a single `OnCheckedChangeListener` for all the checboxes you have. Like

**Checkbox1**

```
CheckBox checkBox1 = findViewById(R.id.check_box1);
checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(checkedChangeListener );
```

**Single `OnCheckedChangeListener` for n no of checkboxes:**

```
CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener checkedChangeListener = new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked)
        {
           switch (buttonView.getId())
           {
               case R.id.check_box1:
                   if (isChecked)
                   {
                      //logic 1
                   }
                    else
                   {
                      //logic 2
                   }
                   ;
                   break;
           }
        }
    };
```

Handle all the checkbox with in switch.

Answer (score 1):

I would like to suggest you to create list of checkboxes. then using For loop or Do While loop create new array with only selected checkboxes.
By this way in new list you will get only checked checkboxes

Answer (score 1):

Use this loop which finds the checkbox by its name:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 32; i++) {
    int id = getResources().getIdentifier("cb" + i, "id", getPackageName());
    CheckBox cb = findViewById(id);
    if (cb.isChecked()) {
        // your code
    }
}
```

this way you can get a list of all your checked checkboxes by a clicklistener of a button:

```
    final ArrayList<CheckBox> checked = new ArrayList<CheckBox>();

    Button button = findViewById(R.id.button);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            checked.clear();

            for (int i = 1; i <= 32; i++) {
                int id = getResources().getIdentifier("cb" + i, "id", getPackageName());
                CheckBox cb = findViewById(id);
                if (cb.isChecked()) {
                    checked.add(cb);
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

Now the list `checked` contains only the checked checkboxes.

Comment: Thanks, didnt know i could find id that way. Anyway please check my comment above. Im looking forward on what you think.